# Removing duplicate account names from an SQLite database (accidental case sensitivity created some duplicates)

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, duplicates

I already searched around for this question but couldn't really find a good answer.

I run dev multiplayer game server mod and I made a huge mistake with the accounts database at first: case sensitivity, so if a player joined with the name 'bob' and 'Bob' was already in the database, a new account was registered (this caused problems!) There's also no 'PRIMARY KEY' column on the database.

So now there's quite a few 'bob', 'Bob', 'BOB', etc duplicates in my database and was wondering if there's a nice way I can clean up the database and remove these duplicates.

The only way I could think of would involve running a loop over the database to store each name in memory (12k records) then running over it again and marking names as "found" then deleting records that were already marked as "found".

Anyway, thanks in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

Insert the result of this into another table then you will not have duplicates

```
SELECT DISTINCT UPPER(name) FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do this in sqlite using a simple delete statement:

```
delete from test where rowid in
( select test.rowid from test
  inner join (select upper(name) name, min(rowid) rowid from test group by upper(name)) t
  on upper(test.name) = t.name and test.rowid <> t.rowid);
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/76f84/10)

Answer (score 0):

I would copy all data to a new table, ignoring duplicates:

```
ALTER TABLE players RENAME TO players_old;
CREATE TABLE players (name TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL COLLATE NOCASE, ...);
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO players SELECT * FROM players_old;
```

This way you will end up with a new table with unique names and a old table with your previous data.